Raspberry PI camera unavailable via Docker OS2
I have a Pi Compute Module 4 running Raspbian 64-bit with 2 camera V3 modules attached.
These work perfectly in Raspbian, but I want to have them available in my docker-container running the image humble-ros2-base.
While I can see the camera using v4l2-ctl --list-devices, I cannot be able to stream the images to a topic.
Are there any resources available about how to do such a setup?
Or am I completely looking into a wrong way of doing things.
Thanks in advance

Did you use v4l2-ctl --list-devices in your docker or your host?
And can you explain how do you start your camera?

To get video devices working in your docker container including controls, you can mount /run/udev into your container:
docker run -v /run/udev:/run/udev YOUR-IMAGE

If you don't need device controls, then it might be sufficient to just add the device to the container:
docker run --device /dev/video0 YOUR-IMAGE

